# Implementing a query, two types of strategies

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, distinct, query-performance

Tables have not been created yet, but to simplify there is a `groups` and an `items` tables. A group contains an item id (and a group id). And several groups may contain the same item id.

For instance

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
          gid int,
          iid int,
          primary key(gid,iid)
);
CREATE TABLE items (
          iid int primary key,
          label char(5)
);
```

and let put some data in these, to help visualize the coming problem

```
insert into items values (1,"pen"),(2,"gum"),(3,"cat"),(4,"dog"),
                         (5,"hug"),(6,"art"),(7,"fun");

insert into groups values(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,1),
                         (3,4),(4,2),(4,3),(4,5),(4,6),(4,7);
```

Retrieving items of multiple groups (e.g. groups 1,2,3,4) uses a `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates

```
(1) SELECT DISTINCT i.iid,i.label FROM groups g JOIN items i ON g.iid=i.iid 
    WHERE g.gid in (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY i.iid;
```

But since the tables will eventually contain more data, would that query using a subquery be more efficient

```
(2) SELECT i.iid,i.label FROM items i 
    JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT iid FROM groups WHERE gid IN (1,2,3,4)) AS s
    ON i.iid=s.iid ORDER BY i.iid;
```

since `distinct` applies only to the items ids, despite the **overhead** of using a subquery?

Or this one suggested by @hypercube (see comments):

```
(3) SELECT i.iid,i.label FROM items AS i 
    WHERE EXISTS
       (SELECT * FROM groups AS g WHERE g.gid IN (1,2,3,4) AND i.iid=g.iid)
    ORDER BY i.iid
```

For information, eventually

- the items table will have between **50~100k** rows
- a group will likely have **5~10k** items
- groups ids to be selected in a single query are in the **5~20** range
- probability that an item is part of 2 selected groups: **50%**
- probability that an item is part of 3 selected groups: **30%**
- probability that an item is part of 4 selected groups: **10%**

Comment: Why not populate the tables with sample data (up to the 100K rows you expect) and test both  queries for performance? And add an index on `(iid, gid)` as well before testing. Some queries may prefer that index.

Comment: You can also test this one: `SELECT i.iid,i.label FROM items AS i WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM groups AS g WHERE g.gid IN (1,2,3,4) AND i.iid=g.iid) ORDER BY i.iid;`

Comment: How many items do you expect to have in a group? There will be performance differences depending on that number: i.e. if some group has only 5 or 10K items, that will affect - differently - the efficiency of each query.

Comment: Question edited (3rd query, and number of items in a group). Thanks for the suggestions, but the whole point of the question was to avoid having to perform multiple tests, and rely on this site people experience ;
 the queries being relatively simple (and sometimes the tests only show speed performance, while under the hood the server might allocate much more memory for a given query - memory is just an example, there could be other reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is simple and straightforward.  It *may* be the most efficient.

(2) is a common speed-up.  But it shines when the non-indexed part (just `i.label` in your case) is bulky and/or the key into the table (`i.id`) is not the `PRIMARY KEY`.  So, if your example is watered down from the real code, (2) *may* outperform (1).

(3) is unlikely to be efficient, since it needs to reach into `items` 50~100K times.

Side issues:

Don't use `CHAR` unless the column really is fixed length; instead, use `VARCHAR`.

I assume you are using InnoDB.  (MyISAM, because of different handling of `PRIMARY KEY`, will be less efficient.)

If `groups` is a many:many mapping table, see my [*tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table).  It will probably help (3) some.